# My code is compiling but is not displalying on the browser

Tags: reactjs

my code is compiling but is not displaying on the browser. although I mistakenly deleted the register service worker file. I don't know if that's the cause but if so, how do I restore the file. Please am beginner

Comment: You need to provide some sort of code for us to look at if you want further help, but without that, I'd recommend running npx create-react-app in a new directory and just copying over the registerServiceWorker file to your app and fix the imports, assuming that is the only issue with why your code doesn't display.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.